# How to type-hint that container subclass always contains particular type?

Tags: python, pycharm, containers, subclass, type-hinting

I'm struggling to get type-hinting to work as I would expect regarding the content types for custom container subclasses in PyCharm.  Let's start with a case that works as I would expect.  You can create a subclass of `list` and specify that it will always have `int` content, and Pycharm then recognizes that each item in such a list will be an `int`.

```py
class IntList(list[int]): pass
il = IntList(())
answer1 = il[0]
```

When I mouse-over `answer1` Pycharm says that it expects this to have type `int`, presumably because the class declaration specified that an `IntList` wouldn't be any old `list`, but instead would be a `list[int]`.  (Never mind the fact that this code would raise an error when run because `il` would be empty. This was just a minimal example to show that PyCharm can sometimes draw type-hinting information from the bracketed `[int]` in the class declaration. The same issues arise in other cases where getting an item from the container wouldn't raise an error.)

So this worked fine when subclassing from `list`. But what I want to do is to create my own generic container class -- call it `Box` -- that could contain a variety of different types of objects.  Then I want to declare my own subclass `IntBox` that will contain only `int` items, and I want PyCharm to recognize this in its various mouse-over hints, auto-completion suggestions, and linting error detection, just like it could for `IntList`.  So here's a very pared-down example of what I'd like.

```py
class Box(list): pass
class IntBox(Box[int]): pass
ib = IntBox(())
answer2 = ib[0]
```

In this case, when I mouse-over `answer2`, PyCharm says that it could have type `Any` and does not recognize that the `[int]` implies that this is not just a generic Box/list, but instead one whose contents have been type-hinted to be `int`.

I've tried all the variations I can imagine using `typing.TypeVar` and `typing.Generic` to try to more explicitly indicate that each subclass of `Box` will have a single type of contents, that `Box.__getitem__` will return that type, and that, for the subclass `IntBox` that type is `int`.

The only solution I've found is that, when I create `ib` I can explicitly declare that this instance has type `IntBox[int]` and then PyCharm will know to expect that `ib[0]` will be an `int`.  But it seems like I shouldn't need to explicitly say that each time I create an `IntBox` instance, and instead there should be some way to get PyCharm to infer this from the `[int]` in the class declaration for `IntBox` just like it could for `IntList`.

Of course this was just a toy example. In the real case that's motivating this, I want my generic container class "Box" to define other methods (not just `__getitem__`) that are type-hinted to return whichever specific type of object the subclass of "Box" in question always contains, where this varies across subclasses.  Using `TypeVar` and `Generic` I can get this to work, *if* I explicitly type-declare that each subclass instance will contain a particular `[contenttype]`, but I can't find a way to get it to work without tedious explicit type-declarations on each instance.

Edit: since solutions that work in the simple case of telling what elements will be in a `list` sub-subclass apparently don't automatically scale up to this real case, here's an example closer to what I need, including that `Box` is a nested `Sequence` rather than a simple `list`, including a `Box.get_first()` method that should also receive type-hinting of `int` for `IntBox`, and including what I think is roughly the right use of `TypeVar`:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Sequence
T = TypeVar('T')
class Box(Sequence[Sequence[T]]):
    def get_first(self:'Box[T]')->T:
        return self[0][0]
class IntBox(Box[int]): pass
ib = IntBox()  # works only if I declare this is type: IntBox[int]
answer = ib.get_first()  # hovering over answer should show it will be int
```

Further edit: the problem with the preceding seems to be the nested  `Sequence[Sequence[T]]`.  Changing this to `Generic[T]` makes things work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`typing.Generic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) to pass a type to the `Box` superclass from a subclass using a [`typing.TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar)

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


class Box(Generic[T], list[T]):
    pass


class IntBox(Box[int]):
    pass


class StrBox(Box[str]):
    pass


ib = IntBox(())
answer1 = ib[0]  # int
sb = StrBox(())
answer2 = sb[0]  # str
```

Comment: you don't even need the `Generic` portion, can just do `class Box(list[T]):`

Comment: You're right that this works in the toy example using `list` as the base container, but I can't seem to get it to do the thing mentioned at the end of the OP, where `Box` is a `Sequence[Sequence[T]]` rather than a `list[T]` and I want a `Box` method like `def get_first(self) -> T:` to show in Pycharm that it will return an `int` if the Box is an `IntBox`, a `str` if the Box is a `StrBox` and so on.   For that, I still seem to need to explicitly type-hint that the instance is of type `IntBox[int]` even though I think Pycharm should be able to tell that from the `Intbox` definition.

Comment: Okay, I ended up figuring out that, if I make my 2D Box be a subclass of `Generic[T]` rather than of `Sequence[Sequence[T]]` then the contents do turn out to be type hinted appropriately for subclasses like `IntBox` and `StrBox`.  That won't help to indicate that `Box` is Sequence-like, but hopefully its having `__len__` and `__getitem__` will do that.  Thanks for your help!